# How to construct a command to join 3 different tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three different tables in MySQL:

[image]

given an user id, how can i get a list of role's name of this user?
For example, user_id = 1
I need a list like this (1, deleteuser, modifyuser, viewuser)

How can I construct my SQL command to get such a list?

Comment: if I searched for `2`, will it return `2, DeleteUser` only? so the number of columns depends on the number of roles of each user? is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. is that possible in SQL?

Comment: last question, what if I want to select `1` and `2`, how will the result look like?

Comment: the result would be a kind of dynamic list. It depends on the number of roles that this user has. I can select one userid at a moment and I can't select for multiple users.

Comment: how about using `GROUP_CONCAT`? does it satisfies your needs? see [Mahmoud's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13284599/491243)

Comment: GUI tools will be some what helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the three tables like so:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  r.Name
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
INNER JOIN roles r ON ur.Role_id = r.id
WHERE u.id = Someid
```

However, if you want the list of roles for each user to be concatenated into one string. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` like so:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(r.Name) roles
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
INNER JOIN role r ON ur.Role_id = r.id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c6b/5)

Comment: also include the usage of `GROUP_CONCAT`, so user will have choices to select among your answer. hehe :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT User_id, Name
FROM User_role
JOIN Role ON User_role.Role_id = Role.Id
WHERE User_id = '1'
```

that would create a list like this:

```
User_id | Name
1       | DeleteUser
1       | ModifyUser
1       | ViewUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT User_id, GROUP_CONCAT(r.Name)
FROM User_Role ur 
INNER JOIN Role r ON ur.Role_id = r.Role_id 
GROUP BY User_id;
```